# Where to store data in order to avoid database hitting?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using webmethod which fetches data from database & storing it in a static variable so that next time it will not hit the database becoz the data is being accessed frequently. Creating static variable doesn't seem to be a proper solution what is an alernative to this scenario.

e.g

```
public static List<SupplierGridData> lstFullSupplierData;

public static List<SupplierGridData> GetProductData()
{
    if (lstFullSupplierData == null)
    {
        //first time get data from database
        lstFullSupplierData = new List<SupplierGridData>();
        lstFullSupplierData  = new POProcess().GetInquiryDetails();
    }
    else
    {
        //use lstFullSupplierData which holds data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is caching:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c.aspx

More specifically, caching data:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx

There is also Session State:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

This comes in the per-application and per-user guise.  And you can also change the backing store of session state.

Comment: @Oded cheers for fixing the links, easy to forget they have the version embedded.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to this could be hitting the db once `if(!this.IsPostBack)` then burying that stuff in the viewstate of the page if it's not too much stuff (assuming you don't need to carry across other pages). Otherwise session or cache will do as other people are suggesting.

Comment: I can not use viewstate becoz i am using PageMethods i.e static methods which do not support viewstate

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your data in session in order to not hit the database again.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx